# Code related web searches

Tags: punctuation, web-search

Is there a way to search the web which does NOT remove punctuation? For example, I want to search for window.window->window (Yes, I actually do, this is a structure in mozilla plugins). I figure that this HAS to be a fairly rare string.

Unfortunately, Google, Bing, AltaVista, Yahoo, and Excite all strip the punctuation and just show anything with the word "window" in it. And according to Google, on their site, at least, there is NO WAY AROUND IT.

In general, searching for chunks of code must be hard for this reason... anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 4):

[google codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch) (["window.window->window"](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=fr&lr=&q=%22window.window-%3Ewindow%22&sbtn=Rechercher) but it doesn't seem to get any relevant result out of this request)

There is similar tools all over the internet like [codase](http://www.codase.com) or [koders](http://www.koders.com/) but I'm not sure they let you search exactly this string. Anyway they might be useful to you so I think they're worth mentioning.

**edit:** It is very unlikely you'll find a general purpose search engine which will allow you to search for something like "window.window->window" because most search engines will do some processing on the document before storing it. For instance they might represent it  internally as vectors of words (a [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model)) and use that to do the search, not the actual original string. And creating such a vector involves first cutting the document according to punctuation and other critters. This is a very complex and interesting subject which I can't tell you much more about. My bad memory did a pretty good job since I studied it at school!

BTW they might do the same kind of processing on your query too. You might want to read about [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) which is probably light years from what google and his friends are doing but can give you a hint about what happens to your query.

Comment: I knew as soon as I read the question that I wasn't going to be fast enough. ;)

Comment: +1 Nice to learn that this doesn't just search the google hosted codebase (I assumed that it did when I saw the name)

Comment: @Sean me too, which is why I didn't think of it!

Comment: Actually, this DOES seem to only search the google codebase... 

And I actually want to search more than just code, because I want to see references to people talking ABOUT it, etc...

Comment: @f4 are you sure? When I do the search, I only get code from google code (not code from google itself, but code google is hosting)

Comment: search for "test" for instance, you'll find code hosted on sourceforge, github...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, by itself in the main Google engine, as you discovered -- however, if you are looking for information about Mozilla then the best bet would be to structure your query something more like this:

```
"window.window->window" +Mozilla 
                     OR +XUL
                        + Another search string related to what you are 
                          trying to do.
```

Answer (score 0):

SymbolHound is a web search that does not remove punctuation from the queries. There is an option to search source code repositories (like the now-discontinued Google Code Search), but it also has the option to search the Internet for special characters. (primarily programming-related sites such as StackOverflow).

try it here: http://www.symbolhound.com

-Tom (co-founder)